# How to open pdf file in new Tab using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: pdf, selenium-webdriver

There's a link of PDF file in website and I want to open it in new Tab and check for for some String using Selenium WebDriver.

Comment: I have found that trying to automate testing of PDFs in a browser a waste of effort. The display of the PDF is usually handled by a plugin rather than the browser. Once the plugin is invoked webdriver losses focus and the test times out. I only test in IE so the behaviour maybe different in other browsers.

Comment: @Lensman could you pls provide me your code to reach upto Pdf in new tab

Comment: You can use the windowhandles to switch to the window that contains  the pdf but I found you can't get any further as the pdf is being rendered by the pdf reader plugin rather than the browser itself. As far as I'm aware the pdf is inaccessible to webdriver, but it's possible that someone else may know otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code while creating Webdriver profile for Chrome driver.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches",Arrays.asList("test-type"));
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> windowTab = new ArrayList<String> 
(driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(windowTab.get(1));
```

You can use this to take the control to new tab, but if many data is present in the pdf it may result in timeout.